# How do I restore a Deja Dup backup (done in Ubuntu) in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, backup, unix

I have pretty much started from scratch on my new installation because I couldn't figure out how to restore the files I backed up on my Linux installation with [Deja Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup). I have GPG Keychain access installed, so what do I need to do to restore the files I had and look at them and see what I want to keep?

I really appreciate any answer you can give :)

Comment: Deja Dup is unknown in the OS X world, you might want to ask in the Deja Dup forum as well.

Answer (score 1):

Deja dup uses duplicity for storage. You may want to use duplicity in the command line, which is available for macOS.

Install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) like this (install Homebrew first if you don't have it yet):

`brew install duplicity`

Then restore with something like:

`duplicity --file-to-restore the/file/you/want/to/restore file:///backup/location /where/you/want/to/restore`

Not sure if this will help OP, but could help other people.

Comment: Can you add some information on how to get duplicity for macOS and how to use it in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) to install the Linux distribution of your choice and then run Deja Dup from there.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and I do have a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu! Thanks a lot, this is the answer I'm looking for!